# I'm new to this...upgrading a Arcade1up Rampage machine to Raspberry Pi

Tags: voltage

You guys will probably laugh at me for asking dumb questions...but...here's my issue.  Any help would be forever appreciated!

I followed the instructions perfectly from a YouTube video by ETA prime...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09DQCOr6zQM&t=1174s&disable_polymer=true

I bought a SD card on Ebay that was pre-loaded with Retropie...

https://www.ebay.com/itm/RetroPie-SD-Card-32gb-for-Raspberry-Pi-3-B-14000-Games-36-Systems/223485417112?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Here's my issue...I hooked everything up exactly like the video and I am getting a lightning bolt at the top right of the screen.  From my limited research, it seems like that is a Low Voltage warning.  However, from further research, it also seems like there might be some software issues.

I have no idea what to do now!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi. We never lough about questions because there are no dump questions, only dump answers ;-) The Raspberry Pi is just made for learning. But please don't expect that we follow videos or tutorials to understand your question, tl;dr. Instead explain what your problem is. You may take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here. At first step to verify your RasPi I suggest to run [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) first.

Comment: start by telling us what model Pi